# typeerror result of expression $(this).simpledialog [undefined] is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, simpledialog

I am following the `http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/string.html` link for creating the dialog using jquery mobile
           i have defined the following in my html

```
 <div data-role="popup" id="Savepopup" class="ui-corner-all" style="background: url(Image/PopupBackground.png); background-size: 100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <div id="datalink">
        <a href="#" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" ><img src="Image/Button.png" width="100%" height="" ></a>
    </div>
    </div>

and in js file i have defined the following



 $(document).delegate('#datalink', 'click', function() {
    $(this).simpledialog({
    'mode' : 'string',
    'prompt' : 'What do you say?',
    'buttons' : {
      'OK': {
        click: function () {
         // var name = text($('#datalink').attr('data-string'));
          //console.log("name name "+name);
          alert("data was entered");
        }
      },
      'Cancel': {
        click: function () { },
        icon: "delete",
        theme: "c"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

but when i click on the button to open dialog i get the error saying $(this).simpledialog is not a function.
What's the mistake i am doing?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have initialized **[jQM-SimpleDialog js](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/install.html)** file because this is a 3rd party dialog implementation, and it cant be found inside a classic jQuery Mobile framework.

If you only need to use basic dialog then I would advise you to use normal jQM **[dialog](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/)**.

Basically your error is saying that simpledialog  function can't be found and that is because it is not initialized.

I made you a working example for classic jQM dialog :http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Jx9xM/

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#mainPage', function(){ 
    $(document).on ('click','#createEvent', function () {        
        $.mobile.changePage('#addCatForm', {
            transition: 'pop',
            changeHash: true,
            role: 'dialog'
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click','#canCat',function () {
        $('#addCatForm').dialog('close');
    });        
});
```